# I need to mask the incoming number and show only last 4 digits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, mask

I want to write a mRender function for j Query datable to give and hide and show link for the incoming data.

I have 2 columns in it one is for description and other is for card number.
Now, when I get card number from the Ajax call, I need to have a show and hide link in 
second column where card number will be displayed.

When data gets populated, it should show 
Show link -

on click of this link it should show
Hide link -

I am new to this j query and java script thing.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks

```
function DisplayCardList() {
    oTable = $('#cardTable').dataTable({
        "aaData": cardList,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "aTargets": [0],
                "sClass": "Card Name",
                "mData": "description"


            },
            {
                "aTargets": [1],
                "sClass": "CardNumber", 
                //I need to write the function here..
            }
        ]
    });
    $('#cardTable').show();
}
```

Comment: So, you want to mask the information, but still have it accessible?

Comment: @David yes.. That is the requirement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will display a 'Show' link in the table cell:

```
'mRender': function (data, type, full) {
          return '<span class=\'hidden\'>' + full[0].substring(full[0].length - 4) + '</span>' +
           '<a href=\'javascript:;\' class=\'hidden\' id=\'hide\'>Hide</a>' +
           '<a href=\'javascript:;\' id=\'show\'>Show</a>';
}
```

javascript click event to handle the show/hide

```
$(document).on("click", "a.show", function (e) {
    // get the clicked object
    var lnk = $(this);
    // toggle its visibility (ie hide the 'Show' link)
    lnk.toggle();
    // toggle visibility of previous element(ie show the 'Hide' link)
    lnk.prev().toggle();
    // toggle visibility of previous element(show the span tag containing the card no)
    lnk.prev().prev().toggle();

});
```

This is a very 'rough & ready' example, but it should get you started and as you're new to jquery, hopefully isn't difficult to understand.  If this meets your requirements then we can refine it.
I would mention that there are legal implications surrounding the storage of card numbers (ie you shouldn't do it unless you have met certain requirements), but I'm guessing this is just an exercise.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I made the required changes and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

When I get your question correctly, you'll need a function to mask a given number - this would be something like this (Regex depends on your number format - it might be possible that you could use a simple `substr` instead):

```
var mask_cc_number = function(cc,masked_char) {

    var masked_char = masked_char || '*',   /* the char using to mask */
        pattern = /^([0-9-]+)([0-9]{4})$/,  /* regex for the given number */
        matches = cc.match(pattern);        /* using the regex */

    return cc.replace(                     
        /([0-9])/g,
        masked_char,
        matches[1]) + matches[2];
    }
```

Next you'll need to add the masked number and the original number to a HTML container, and on click you'll need to toggle the display of the numbers:

```
var num = '1234-4567-7890-4433'; /* example */
    container = $('<div class="cc-container"></div>');

container
    .append('<div class="masked-cc">'+mask_cc_number(num)+'</div>')
    .append('<div class="cc">'+num+'</div>');

$('#YOUR_EXISTING_HTML_CONTAINER')
    .append(container)
    .on('click','.cc-container',function() {
        var elm = $(this),
            mc = elm.find('.masked-cc'),
            c = elm.find('.cc');
        if(mc.is(':visible')) {
            mc.hide(); 
            c.show();
        } else {
            mc.show();
            c.hide();
        }
    });
```

I put this together in a small [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mf37s3e1/) for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use native JS, as I don't know jQuery, but this would seem to be the easiest way since you know exactly what you're masking, and what you want to display.

```js
function showData(id){
  alert(document.getElementById(id).getAttribute('data-data'));
}
function toggleData(id){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    // If masked
    if(elem.innerHTML.indexOf("XXXX") > -1){
        elem.innerHTML = elem.getAttribute("data-data");
    }
    // Else mask it
    else{
        elem.innerHTML = "XXXX-XXXX-" + elem.getAttribute("data-data").substr(-4);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="maskedInfo" data-data="1234-5678-9012">XXXX-XXXX-9012</div>
<button onclick="showData('maskedInfo')">Show Data</button>
<button onclick="toggleData('maskedInfo')">Toggle Data</button>
```

Basically just store the unmasked data in a `data-*` attribute, and read from that. You could also use a similar method to toggle what is shown.